# why isn't possible to create two public classes in the current package in java?

Tags: java

```
package payroll;

public class Employee{

    private int id;
    int hours;
    protected float rate;
    private static int count;

    public Employee(int h, float r){
        id = 101 + count++;
        hours = h;
        rate = r;
    }

    public Employee(){
        this(0, 50);
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public int getHours(){
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(int value){
        hours = value;
    }

    public float getRate(){
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(float value){
        rate = value;
    }

    public double getNetIncome(){
        double income = hours * rate;
        int ot = hours - 180;
        if(ot > 0) income += 50 * ot;
        return income;
    }

    public static int countEmployees(){
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain what your question is exactly, instead of just dumping a code snippet and letting people guess what your question is.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* have multiple public classes in the same package.

However, most Java compilers have restrictions about which *file* a top-level (i.e. non-nested) public class can occur in - you can't declare a top-level public class Foo in Bar.java. That means you can't create two public classes within the same file. Perhaps that's what you're running into?

So this isn't valid:

```
// In Foo.java
package testpackage;

public class Foo {}
public class Bar {}
```

But this is:

```
// In Foo.java
package testpackage;

public class Foo {}


// In Bar.java
package testpackage;

public class Bar {}
```

Comment: +1. Bar can also easily be a subclass of Foo in file Foo.java:
public class Foo{
  public class Bar{}
}

Comment: This restriction applies to public top level classes. You can have any number of public nested classes in the same file. ;)

Comment: @Peter: Good point - will edit.

Comment: A common trick I use if someone has posted multiple classes to get it compiling is to create an outer interface and paste all the code into it as nested classes. This avoids needing to break all the classes into files with the right name. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is what the Java specification has to say on the issue:

> When packages are stored in a file system (§7.2.1), the host system may choose to enforce the restriction that it is a compile-time error if a type is not found in a file under a name composed of the type name plus an extension (such as .java or .jav) if either of the following is true:
>
> - The type is referred to by code in other compilation units of the package in which the type is declared.
> - The type is declared public (and therefore is potentially accessible from code in other packages).
>
> This restriction implies that there must be at most one such type per compilation unit. This restriction makes it easy for a compiler for the Java programming language or an implementation of the Java virtual machine to find a named class within a package; for example, the source code for a public type wet.sprocket.Toad would be found in a file Toad.java in the directory wet/sprocket, and the corresponding object code would be found in the file Toad.class in the same directory.

A result of the above is that you cannot have two top-level public classes in the same file. This makes it easier to locate classes within packages.